# Android Studio gone nuts all of a sudden

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart

[image]

Firstly, Look at the screenshot that I've attached, It is giving me red lines (look to the right) in my entire code (386 errors in 766 lines) all of a sudden (This project was working perfectly fine last time I tested it), It is saying that the import package line is not valid, I thought it would be something with the SDK so I redownloaded Dart SDK but still getting the same error, I redownloaded flutter zip file and added it to my path, also updated it's path in project settings still didn't work, I tried running flutter doctor command and it is saying everything is perfect, I have selected Android SDK too still no help, I even tried reinstalling Android Studio, didn't work either.

(Please help me out with it :( My First Internship is starting soon and I cannot work without android studio)

I have a feeling that it has to do something with the configuration but I can't figure out what to change :/

Comment: Does it happen in other projects too?

Comment: Try running `flutter pub get`.

Comment: Solved, Everytime I do Flutter Clean it somehow gives these errors and doing pub get fixes them :) Simple Solution but works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually It was very easy to fix, Just run

```
flutter pub get
```

It will work after running this command

[image]

Answer (score 4):

**Try any or all of these**

1. Try cleaning/rebuilding the project
2. Change SDK path
3. Go to your projects main folder in the file explorer and delete the .gradle. Close the project, reopen and let Android Studio redownload the deleted files.
4. Update Android Studio
5. Uninstall Android Studio and make sure to delete all Android Studio's app data. Once you've done that go to the android page and download Android Studio from the so you have the latest version. Sometimes the IDE has old files that somehow affect your projects.
6. Check your `gradle-wrapper.properties` in your app within Android Studio. Make sure the second line `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-bin.zip` is the latest version which is 7.2.

Comment: Tried changing SDK Path, didn't work

Comment: Tried making new projects but it is stuck in infinite loop of dialogue box saying "Creating new Project", Also Updated Android Studio didn't help, Clean Installed Android Studio still no help will check 6th point when i get back home

Comment: When you uninstalled Android Studio did you make sure to delete EVERY file related to it?

Comment: Yeah except my Projects

Comment: I fixed the Issue by updating plugins, Old Projects still give error but new ones are working, Except it is taking a lot of time to run now, Like 5-10 mins to build an app on 16 Thread CPU with 16 GB ram and m.2 ssd .... Something is definitely not right, I remember compiling it in much lesser time before this issue occurred

Comment: Did you try my sixth suggestion?

Comment: Actually My Android Studio started working so I didn't try the sixth one, Though where can I find this gradle thing?

Comment: Open your project and expand Gradle Scripts then go to gradle-wrapper.properties(Gradle Version). If your distributionUrl is under 7.2, you can copy and paste my 6th suggestion there. After that sync the project and your project should hopefully work.

Answer (score 3):

This happens to me sometimes. I do the following which usually fixes it.

1. Click the build menu then Clean Project.
2. Click file, Invalidate Caches.
3. Check off all the options on the box that appears.
4. Restart Android Stuido.

The project will rebuild when Android Studio starts back up and the errors should be gone.

Comment: The problem is there with new projects too :/ Something is wrong with the Studio itself, Are you sure rebuilding will fix it? I'll try it out